# How to add higest ten values from odd/even columns in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I tried to combine sumproduct and large like this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(((MOD(COLUMN(E48:AD48),2)=1)*E48:AD48),ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))))
```

This worked for odd columns. When I changed 1 to 0, it didn't work for even columns. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula looks **OK** to me....but it needs to be `"array entered"` with

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

.....so that curly braces appear around the formula in the formula bar - did you do that?

For a "non-array" version you can try this:

`=SUM(LARGE((E48,G48,I48,K48,M48,O48,Q48,S48,U48,W48,Y48,AA48,AC48),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))`

but there will need to be at least 10 values in those cells, otherwise you get an error